# Programmatically package a MATLAB toolbox

Tags: matlab

The toolbox packaging functionality new in R2014b looks pretty nice.

However, you seem to be able to package a toolbox only via the toolbox-packaging GUI.

I'd like to be able to create a `.prj` file interactively using the GUI, and then *programmatically* package the toolbox using this `.prj` file, incorporating this programmatic step into a wider build process (which also includes checking things out, running a unit-test suite etc).

Does anyone know of a way to do this (documented or not, supported or not)?

I took a look at `MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\toolbox_packaging\+matlab\+tbxpkg\+internal\create.m` - this seems to mostly do the job, but it requires that the `.prj` file is in a specific location relative to the toolbox folder.

I was hoping for something similar to the app-building classes such as `matlab.apputil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of R2016a there is new functionality to [programmatically package a toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2016a/matlab/ref/matlab.addons.toolbox.packagetoolbox.html).